# ComboBox DataBinding C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 Tables:
Diagnose: ID, Name
DiagnoseForPatients: PatientID, DiagnoseID.

I have A DateGridView with 2 ComboBoxes: First ComboBox needs to show the ID of the Diagnose, And the second one needs to show the name.
When I'm adding a new row to my DataGridView I'm Getting an Exception saying DiagnoseID Can't be null (although I chose ID On first ComboBox).

I'm using this code to add the ComboBox's to my DataGridView:

```
     ClinicTableAdapters.DiagnoseTableAdapter daDiagnoses = new ClinicTableAdapters.DiagnoseTableAdapter();
     Clinic.DiagnoseDataTable dtDiagnosesAdd = daDiagnoses.GetData();

     DgDiagnosesAdd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     col1.HeaderText = "ID";
     col1.DataPropertyName = "ID";
     col1.Name = "ID";
     col1.ValueMember = "ID";
     col1.DisplayMember = "ID";
     col1.DataSource = dtDiagnosesAdd;
     DgDiagnosesAdd.Columns.Add(col1);

     col2.HeaderText = "Name";
     col2.DataPropertyName = "Name";
     col2.Name = "Name";
     col2.ValueMember = "Name";
     col2.DisplayMember = "Name";
     col2.DataSource = dtDiagnosesAdd;
     DgDiagnosesAdd.Columns.Add(col2);
```

I'm using the DataGridView For Adding Diagnoses For patient. The DataGridView Is binded to DiagnosesForPatients DataTable.
How can I bind the DiagnoseID?
ON WPF VB.NET I use:

```
cmb.SelectedValueBinding = New Binding("DiagnoseID")
```

How should I Write it on WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One column is enough for handling "Diagnose" information

```
DgDiagnosesAdd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
col1.HeaderText = "Diagnose";
//Next line will bind DiagnoseForPatients.DiagnoseID to Diagnose.ID
col1.DataPropertyName = "DiagnoseID";
col1.Name = "DiagnosesDiagnoseID";
col1.ValueMember = "ID";
col1.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Name column will be used as display text
col1.DataSource = dtDiagnosesAdd;
DgDiagnosesAdd.Columns.Add(col1);
```

About *Exception saying DiagnoseID Can't be null*

Seems like `DiagnoseID` column's property `AllowDbNull = false`.

Set `DataColumn.AllowDbNull = true`
Or set `DataColumn.DefaultValue = 1` or some other default value for column

If you haven't access to the DataTable's column, then you can set default values for new rows in the `DataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded` eventhandler

```
private void DataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(Object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int comboBoxColumnIndex = 1;
    int diagnoseIDDefaultValue = 1;
    e.Row.Cells[ComboBoxColumnIndex].Value = diagnoseIDDefaultValue;
}
```

Comment: But what if I need to show Both - DiagnoseID and DiagnoseName?

Comment: Then create another column with different `DisplayMember`, like you did in the question. `DataPropertyName` was a main point